# Using the @property decorator and dunder methods

Tags: python, python-decorators

Whilst debugging some code I found an unexpected behaviour using the `@property` decorator. Simplified version is as follows:

```
class TestClass:

    @property
    def __len__(self):
        return 6


test_instance = TestClass()
print(len(test_instance))
```

I'd expect this to print 6, but instead I get a TypeError: `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`

Without the property decorator this works fine. I can also `print(test_instance.__len__)` without issue. I'm struggling to get my head around why this may be the case and was hoping someone can explain it in simple terms.

Edit:
For a non-dunder method this also works as I'd expect:

```
class TestClass:

    @property
    def foobar(self):
        return 6


test_instance = TestClass()
print(test_instance.foobar)
```

`6`  is printed as expected. My understanding is that `len(Class)` is syntactic sugar to call the `__len__` method, which is why I'm confused here

Comment: Why did you expect that to print `6`? How did you expect that to work?

Comment: Why are you trying to turn dunder methods to properties? what are you actually trying to solve? `len(obj)` calls `obj.__len__()`. Trying to make `__len__` a property is essentially equivalent to `6()` (in this case at least), hence the error about `int` not being `callable`

Comment: Properties are used to write something as if it's an attribute and have it call a method instead. Your attempt would work if the normal way to get the length of an object were `obj.__len__`. But since it's normally a method, you don't need a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`len` tries to call `test_instance.__len__`, but now that it's a property, that attribute access evaluates to `6`, not a function.

If you simply want an instance of `TestClass` to have a hard-coded length of 6, don't use a property.

```
class TestClass:
    def __len__(self):
        return 6
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I was maybe misunderstanding the purpose of properties. I don't want a fixed value here - that was just sufficient to demonstrate the problem. In reality I have class methods which take a while to compute so I've been using `@cached_property` to save unnecessary recomputation. I guess I should be careful to disambiguate between `@cache` and `@cached_property` in future.